# undefined method for Devise "send_reset_password_instructions"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, devise

Did three things:

made sure Devise integrated in "routes.rb"

```
devise_for :accesses
```

Integrated Devise in model "access.rb"

```
class Access < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UUIDHelper

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :verification
  belongs_to :actor, autosave: true

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates :username, uniqueness: true
  validates_length_of :username, maximum: 64
  validates_length_of :username, minimum: 3

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string. Used for SEEDS FILE
  def Access.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
        BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
end
```

the command for resetting password in "access_controller.rb"

```
  def recoverAccount
    myAccess = Access.find_by email: params[:access][:email]
    myAccess.send_reset_password_instructions
  end
```

"send_reset_password_instructions" and other methods from Devise throws an undefined method; what did I do wrong? what did I miss?

EDIT:

I just figured out something new; #before_filter :authenticate_user! Does not work; I followed through proper installation but I dont know why it doesnt work.

Comment: There's no such method in devise, buddy.

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Recoverable/ClassMethods @hd1

Comment: please paste the `myAccess` variable value.

Comment: @AmitSharma

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"qROsTir20jKJzw8oU3G3woMmoN7hhU2BzzG41rl1+30FX7YLMig10ciaM4Lrg6sjUkpmYAoFROj3e3eEq7g8hg==",
 "access"=>{"email"=>"sample@gmail.com"}}

Comment: Make sure that `myAccess` isn't nil. In my case, I got `undefined method 'send_reset_password_instructions' for nil:NilClass`. This can also happen if you have a class User that doesn't have `devise: recoverable` and do `User.send_reset_password_instructions`. Very common mistake when subclassing User.